# iOS Push Notifications: How to get the "Notification identifier" within the delegate

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

When I send a Push Notification over APNs to my iOS Apps mostly everything works fine. The notification will be received and I can read the payload from the `userInfo` Dictionary of the `application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler` method.

But `userData` does not contain the Notification Identifier, which is part of the new Notification Format since iOS 7, although Apple describes `userInfo` this way:

> A dictionary that contains information related to the remote notification, potentially including a badge number for the app icon, an alert sound, an alert message to display to the user, a notification identifier, and custom data.

So, is there any way to get the notification identifier from within my app, after the notification has been delivered? Or will the identifier only be used by the feedback service?

Comment: did you get notification Identifier

Answer (score 0):

Use the new API `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` introduced in iOS 10.
Set the Delegate on the `UNUserNotificationCenter` and the following method is called when a push message is received.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, 
                          didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, 
               withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
```

There you will find everything in `UNNotificationResponse`.